# PHP Incomplete class Object Error on creating a custom Checkout flow Plugin in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, commerce

I have created the custom checkout flow plugin in drupal 8. And added the required steps in it as per the the commerce2 documentation. See the code below.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_custom\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow;

use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowWithPanesBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * @CommerceCheckoutFlow(
 *  id = "custom_checkout_flow",
 *  label = @Translation("Custom checkout flow"),
 * )
 */
class CustomCheckoutFlow extends CheckoutFlowWithPanesBase {



    public function getSteps() {

        return  [
            'order_information' => [
                'label' => $this->t('Order information'),
                'has_sidebar' => TRUE,
                'previous_label' => $this->t('Go back'),
            ],
            'shipping_options' => [
                'label' => $this->t('Shipping Methods'),
                'has_sidebar' => TRUE,
                'previous_label' => $this->t('Go back')
            ],
            'review' => [
                'label' => $this->t('Review'),
                'next_label' => $this->t('Continue to review'),
                'previous_label' => $this->t('Go back'),
                'has_sidebar' => TRUE,
            ],
        ] + parent::getSteps();
    }

}
```

And enable the checkout flow and applied it in the commerce order configurations. Even I am able to open the edit checkout flow page but when I am setting an view to the order information pane. I am getting the response code 500.

And the error I got is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Drupal\\commerce_checkout\\Plugin\\Commerce\\CheckoutPane\\CheckoutPaneBase::defaultConfiguration(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;Drupal\\commerce_custom\\Plugin\\Commerce\\CheckoutFlow\\CustomCheckoutFlow&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  in /var/www/html/labeloutlet_web/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/checkout/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane/CheckoutPaneBase.php on line 106, referer: http://localhost/labeloutlet_web/web/admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows/manage/custom_checkout_flow?destination=/labeloutlet_web/web/admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows
```

So my question is how to resolve this error and being able th change the configurations of the pane inside a custom checkout flow plugin.